# Vagrant: missing destination file operand after ‘/etc/exports’

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, vagrant

I'm running Vagrant 1.7.3 with an Ubuntu 14.04 basebox, and I want to try out the new Puppet 4.2.0.

However, when I run `vagrant up` on an empty VM, I get the following error:

```
cp: missing destination file operand after ‘/etc/exports’
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
cp: cannot stat ‘/exports’: No such file or directory
```

My `/etc/exports` file:

```
# VAGRANT-BEGIN: 1000 b814b4c0-189a-4d39-9283-dd6678993f9e
"/home/xx/puppetmaster/src/manifests" 172.28.128.99(rw,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,fsid=2596711920)
# VAGRANT-END: 1000 b814b4c0-189a-4d39-9283-dd6678993f9e
```

My Vagrant file:

```
machine.vm.synced_folder "~/puppetmaster/src/manifests", "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/development/manifests", { :nfs => true }
```

Where is the problem? The strange thing is it worked just fine last week.
The folders are apparently being imported correctly, anyway.

Additionally whenever I destroy my VM and start it again, Vagrant makes a new entry in `/etc/exports`.
Now I have the `Vagrant-Begin` and `Vagrant-End` statement around 5 times in my exports file.

Answer (score 1):

See a ticket: [cp: cannot stat ‘/exports’: No such file or directory](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5951):

> This is happening because $TMPDIR is not set on your local machine. Sorry about that. I've opened #5954 to fix the issue. In the meantime, a workaround is to `export TMPDIR=/tmp` and things should begin working again.

[Fixed](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/5954). Fix available since 1.7.4

Comment: How do I apply your fix? After adding /tmp to my path I get the error that /etc/exports can't be created because it lacks the necessary rights. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to sudo a Vagrant Up.

Comment: @Pulz, 1) Update `Vagrant` 2) Remove `/tmp` from your path

Comment: your last problem: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5957 . Fixed. Fix available since 1.7.4

Answer (score -1):

This is what works for me:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/source/path", "/dest/path", :nfs => true, mount_options: ['rw', 'vers=3', 'tcp', 'fsc']
```